# Consulta mysql almacenada en variable PHP

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo una tabla de datos de cuestionarios que básicamente guardan número para ser evaluados:

```
 id   |   PIN    | respuesta1 | respuesta2 | respuesta3 |
  1      0BGEE          1            1            1
  2      0BGEE          0            1            0
  3      0BGEE          1            0            1
  4      1BGZZ          1            1            1
  5      0BGEE          1            1            1
```

Cómo puedo sumar todos los datos de un campo específico pero únicamente tomando los que tienen el PIN '0BGEE' sin incluir '1BGZZ'??
Por ejemplo en respuesta1 el valor de toda esa columna tomando unicamente el pin '0BGEE' sería igual a 3.

Les muestro la consulta que tengo y que estoy almacenando en una variable PHP para mostrarlo después:
Esto me devuelve error.

```
$cuenta = mysqli_query($conecta, "SELECT PIN, count (respuesta1)AS suma FROM 
respuestas_cuestionario GROUP BY PIN");
$total = mysqli_num_rows($cuenta);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías hacer una consulta así:

```
SELECT SUM(respuesta1) AS respuesta1
FROM respuestas_cuestionario
WHERE PIN = '0BGEE'
GROUP BY PIN
```

Comment: @Aprendiz, ahí modifiqué el query para que siempre sume uno.  Por favor probalo ahora.

Comment: Son muy amables, pero únicamente quiero sumar la columna respuesta1 con el pin '0BGEE' y probé como me muestras @GustavoCantero y no me suma correctamente.

Comment: @SuriGang'sHallen, por favor se un poco más claro, porque el primer comentario decía que no debía sumar.  ¿Qué es lo que necesitas que haga?

Comment: ¿Pero entonces cuál era el problema del primer query que te pasé?  Porque hacía eso, sumaba las respuestas.

Comment: Lamento si no fui específico @Gustavo Cantero, pero si escribí que sólo quiero sumar los datos de la columna respuesta1 que cumplan con el pin = OBGEE, solo de la columna respuesta1

Comment: @SuriGang'sHallen listo, por favor probá ahora

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo @Gustavo Cantero

Answer (score 0):

**USO DE FUNCIÓN COUNT**

---

Tu consulta me parece correcta, solo que incompleta; es decir eStas agrupando pero no filtras, entonces antes del `GROUP BY` debería existir un `WHERE` así

```
WHERE PIN = "OBGEE"
```

Consulta completa

```
SELECT PIN, count (respuesta1)AS suma 
FROM respuestas_cuestionario 
WHERE PIN = "OBGEE" 
GROUP BY PIN
```

> No deberías `sumar` como indicas en los comentarios, pues si acaso el valor es distinto de 1 en esa columna entonces el resultado será mayor o menor a 3 pero nunca ese

Explicacion

Obtienes 3 Usando `SUM` pero no por que te indique que existen 3 elementos con dicho `PIN` sino por qué está sumando el valor **1** de cada renglón.

Si por otro lado en lugar de **1** cada renglón tuviera **2** entonces te devolvería **6**, por eso el comentario de usar `COUNT`

**ACTUALIZACION**

**USO DE FUNCIÓN SUM**

---

Dejo lo anterior como referencia pero viendo las aclaraciones que haces en los comentarios entonces si usa `SUM`, la estructura será igual solo cambia la función

```
SELECT PIN, SUM(respuesta1)AS suma 
FROM respuestas_cuestionario 
WHERE PIN = "OBGEE" 
GROUP BY PIN
```

Como ya te comentaba la suma condicionada vendrá de la función `sum` en conjunto con el uso de `WHERE`

- Solo considera tomar en cuenta las observaciones que te hice mas arriba en mi respuesta

**Referencias**

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/counting-rows.html
- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum